# .NET Core - Self Contained Deployment not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, web-deployment

I have a .NET Core Web Application. I'm using the [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) command to create a [self contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).

It creates the files and appears to create .net core dlls, but when runnning in IIS on Windows 10, I still need to install the [.NET Core Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) to get it to work. After installing .NET Core Hosting bundle it works fine.

I have reviewed a lot of other posts before asking, but can't find the answer.

By default IIS gives the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 500.19 – Internal Server Error

My Publish command:

```
dotnet publish "mydirectory\mywebsite.csproj" --self-contained --framework netcoreapp2.1 -r win10-x64 -c Release
```

The csproj looks like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-mywebsite-656GASF8-B9H4-5963-1038-5D735B609E15</UserSecretsId>
      <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here are the published files.

[image]

I thought maybe the 'l1-1-0' part might be the wrong framework version, but my dotnet version is 2.1.500.

[image]

What do I need to do to get it to work please?

Comment: "After installing .NET Core Hosting bundle it works fine." Then why do you ask this question? The answer is so clear.

Comment: @Lex Li - Because a self contained install should install the framework as well to save having to do it separately. Think the downvote was a bit harsh for a legitimate and well researched post.

Comment: Unfortunately it is you who don't understand the topic. Microsoft defines what is "self contained" (so ASP.NET Core module is not there by design) and that's just what you observed. Unless you have the power to force Microsoft changes its mind, this question has no answer. https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4

Comment: Then please kindly tell me what I'm misunderstanding - even after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ as well as many other docs . What is even the point of a self contained install if you have to install the framework anyway?

Comment: The article I cited states for self contained deployments: All components, including both the .NET Core libraries and the .NET Core runtime, are included with the application and are isolated from other .NET Core applications.

Comment: The key points for self deployment are 1) in the separate download only ASP.NET Core module for IIS matters (the runtime bundled is ignored). 2) you decide what runtime is shipped with your web app, not the separate installer. Whether that's a good design or not is something you can challenge Microsoft on. Such are implicitly mentioned in Microsoft docs, and you can only figure them out by experiments.

Comment: Argh. That's annoying, but thanks for explaining. If you want to state that as the answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lex Li's comment/ [blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4) contains the answer. I'm detailing it here to try to save someone else losing days to this simple misunderstanding.

> A self contained deployment does indeed include the [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), but
>   it doesn't include the `ASP.NET Core module for IIS` which you get
>   when you download the `Runtime & Hosting Bundle` from the [.net downloads
>   page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0).

So if you are deploying to IIS, you will need to run the `Runtime & Hosting Bundle` installer even for a self contained deployment.

A self contained deployment just means the application will use the .NET Core Runtime packaged with the application rather than whatever is installed on the machine.

Comment: I could not find this information anywhere in the official documentation. They should indeed add it.

Comment: From this info, I changed _self contained_ to _framework dependent_ while setting the IIS 8.0 AppPool to _no managed code_ to successfully get the web app running ASP.NET 5 working on Windows 2012 server.  <3