# Deploying .net core to IIS

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to deploy .net core 3.1 Test Web API application into IIS and I am getting error 500.19 error code 0x8007000d. Can you please help me to identify what is wrong with the config file. Here is the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\Test.exe"
                    stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                    stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                    hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Using Jexus manager I generated a report and it says Invalid certificate, I installed IIS manager on my local machine and tried to browse using localhost and it returns error 404.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure a .net core API to work in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612351/how-do-i-configure-a-net-core-api-to-work-in-iis)

Comment: I have both of the .net core 3.1 and ASP.Net Module installed. I was able to run the application in stand alone. It seems that the problem is coming from IIS

Comment: Run some basic diagnostics and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi, some strange thing is happening, I added the site in jexsusmanager and whenever i try to browse to it, error 404 is displayed.

Comment: Generate a report and edit your question to include it. That should reveal enough information for others to review.

Comment: report was generated and it says invalid certificate but i am using local host, no experience with iis

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by installing the hosting bundle. I am doing self contained deployment, so why do i need that?

Comment: Explained quite well in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113388/net-core-self-contained-deployment-not-working

Comment: You are the man. I was confused....Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core - Self Contained Deployment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113388/net-core-self-contained-deployment-not-working)